# Finding average of values in the past 2 minutes in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, analytics

I am trying to find average of values that are within a certain time frame within the same data.table and save it to a new column.

Below is a sample data set

## Updated the dataset to represent the discontinuous timeline in my original dataset.

```
> x
                     ts value avg
 1: 2015-01-01 00:00:23     9   0
 2: 2015-01-01 00:01:56    11   0
 3: 2015-01-01 00:02:03    18   0
 4: 2015-01-01 00:03:16     1   0
 5: 2015-01-01 00:05:19     6   0
 6: 2015-01-01 00:05:54    16   0
 7: 2015-01-01 00:06:27    13   0
 8: 2015-01-01 00:06:50     7   0
 9: 2015-01-01 00:08:41    12   0
10: 2015-01-01 00:09:08    17   0
11: 2015-01-01 00:09:28     8   0
12: 2015-01-01 00:10:56     5   0
13: 2015-01-01 00:11:44    10   0
14: 2015-01-01 00:12:23    20   0
15: 2015-01-01 00:12:28     2   0
16: 2015-01-01 00:12:37    15   0
17: 2015-01-01 00:12:42     4   0
18: 2015-01-01 00:12:48    19   0
19: 2015-01-01 00:13:41     3   0
20: 2015-01-01 00:16:04    14   0
```

My code assigns value 10.5 to all the rows and I donot get the expected results. Here is my code.

```
require(lubridate)
x[, avg :=  x[ts>=ts-minutes(2) & ts<=ts , mean(value)], verbose=TRUE  ]
```

## Updated

I want the results to be as below

```
                   ts   value   avg
1   01-01-2015 00:00:23 9   0
2   01-01-2015 00:01:56 11  9
3   01-01-2015 00:02:03 18  10
4   01-01-2015 00:03:16 1   14.5
5   01-01-2015 00:05:19 6   0
6   01-01-2015 00:05:54 16  6
7   01-01-2015 00:06:27 13  11
8   01-01-2015 00:06:50 7   11.66666667
9   01-01-2015 00:08:41 12  7
10  01-01-2015 00:09:08 17  12
11  01-01-2015 00:09:28 8   14.5
12  01-01-2015 00:10:56 5   12.5
13  01-01-2015 00:11:44 10  5
14  01-01-2015 00:12:23 20  7.5
15  01-01-2015 00:12:28 2   11.66666667
16  01-01-2015 00:12:37 15  9.25
17  01-01-2015 00:12:42 4   10.4
18  01-01-2015 00:12:48 19  9.333333333
19  01-01-2015 00:13:41 3   11.666667
20  01-01-2015 00:16:04 14  0
```

I want to do this to a data with a larger data set, also with min and max values in separate columns separately( here I have shown only the average function). Any help would be great.

## Updated

Below is the reproducible code.

```
#reproducible code
ts<-  seq(from=ISOdatetime(2015,1,1,0,0,0,tz="GMT"),to=ISOdatetime(2015,1,1,0,0,19,tz="GMT"), by="sec")
set.seed(2)
ts <-ts + seconds(round(runif(20,0,1000),0))
value <- 1:20
avg <- 0
x <- data.table(ts,value,avg)  
setkey(x,ts)
x
```

## Solution

Thanks to @Saksham for poining me towards apply functions. Here is the solution that I have come up with.

```
find <- function(y){
  mean(x[ts>=y-minutes(2) & ts<y,value])
}
x$avg <- mapply(find,x[,ts])
> x
                     ts value       avg
 1: 2015-01-01 00:00:23     9       NaN
 2: 2015-01-01 00:01:56    11  9.000000
 3: 2015-01-01 00:02:03    18 10.000000
 4: 2015-01-01 00:03:16     1 14.500000
 5: 2015-01-01 00:05:19     6       NaN
 6: 2015-01-01 00:05:54    16  6.000000
 7: 2015-01-01 00:06:27    13 11.000000
 8: 2015-01-01 00:06:50     7 11.666667
 9: 2015-01-01 00:08:41    12  7.000000
10: 2015-01-01 00:09:08    17 12.000000
11: 2015-01-01 00:09:28     8 14.500000
12: 2015-01-01 00:10:56     5 12.500000
13: 2015-01-01 00:11:44    10  5.000000
14: 2015-01-01 00:12:23    20  7.500000
15: 2015-01-01 00:12:28     2 11.666667
16: 2015-01-01 00:12:37    15  9.250000
17: 2015-01-01 00:12:42     4 10.400000
18: 2015-01-01 00:12:48    19  9.333333
19: 2015-01-01 00:13:41     3 11.666667
20: 2015-01-01 00:16:04    14       NaN
```

Comment: You may try `library(RcppRoll);x[, Avg:=c(value[1L],roll_mean(value,2))]`

Comment: @akrun my actual data set has multiple "values" for different minute/second combinations in separate rows. So in that case when I want to find the average of all the values within 2 minutes, I might need to look into more than two rows dynamically. So I need something where I can specify the time range.

Comment: If all your rows contain data strictly for equidistant timestamps, you can just use `rollmean()` from `{zoo}` library (there are also functions for rollmax, rollmin etc)

Comment: @MaksimGayduk Unfortunately I don't have equidistant time stamps

Comment: @MaksimGayduk  `roll_mean` from `RcppRoll` is much faster.

Comment: you might want to use `foverlaps`

Comment: One of these days :-) I'll finish porting some code I wrote in Matlab to do just this.  If you want to peek, go to FileExchange and grab `rollstat`  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52553  .  This function takes an argument to set a constant "elapsed time" value rather than a set number of values.

Comment: make your example representative of your problem/real data set.

Comment: @Khashaa I have updated the question now. Can you please promote the question? Thanks

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Looks like that exactly what I need :) Great to know that you are working on the port. Did you try to achieve this in R using data.table? Is it not entirely possible to achieve this using data.table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do

```
ts[,avg] <- ts[,val] - 0.5
```

As logically and seeing your expected result, it is doing the same thing. You can edit you expected result to make it more flexible if I interpreted it wrong.

**EDIT:**

This base R approach should do the trick. As I an not familiar with manipulating time, I am assuming that arithmetic works in the same way as it does in most of the languages

```
interval <- minutes(2) #Assuming this is how we define 5 minutes

x$avg <- apply( x, 1, function(y){
               mean(x$value[x$time > ( y["time"]) - interval ) && x$time < y["time"]])
               })
```

Comment: My data set is just an example. And in this case, my expected result so happens that it can be achieved through a simple subtraction. However I want to be able to average values within a given time range, for my real life usage.

Comment: you don't seem to be using the column "value" anywhere atall. FYI - you can set the time interval using interval<-minutes(2) from lubridate package.

Comment: @pauljeba. sorry for the errors as I am a beginner in `R`. Can you please validate now

Comment: thank you for pointing me towards the direction of apply functions. Yours' gave the idea, I was able to figure out the complete solution. Thanks!