# immediate average of a value in past 1000 seconds

Tags: c#, average

I have a score variable which can grow and shrink every iteration of the main loop.

It's required to get the average of the score in the past 1000 seconds. (That is, I need a Simple Moving Average)

[This question is relevant, but I wouldn't want to keep track of any score values from previous frames.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524371/finding-average-of-values-in-the-past-2-minutes-in-a-data-table)

The most straightforward approach to compute average is to keep a list of scores, paired with a timestamp a score was recorded at.

Every frame, we iterate through the list, and sum up `score*deltaTime`, where `deltaTime` is to be computed as `(ourTimestamp - prevTimeStamp) / 1000sec.` The result of sum is our average value of past 1000 sec for this frame.
We will dispose of any old elements in the list which have timestamp that is older than 1000 sec from "right-now"

The above approach will be memory consuming. Is there a simpler approach to compute average immediately, without keeping this "trail list"?

Comment: You may want to tag the language you're coding (and want the solution) in.

Comment: You don't need to keep historical values.  Just add `this-score` with `running-total` and write to `running-total`.  That's one value. To get the average, you just divide by the number of samples with respect to the time interval.  It's exactly the same as you calculate _running frames per second_

Comment: Anyway, SO is about specific problems, not how to optimise code.  Perhaps another Stack Exchange site?

Comment: @MickyD: You are alljuding to the algorithm for the *cumulative moving average*, but the question is about the *simple moving average*.

Comment: @EricLippert oh.  Thanks learnt something new :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The above approach will be memory consuming.

Correct.

> Is there a simpler approach to compute average immediately, without keeping this "trail list"?

Nope.

There is a simpler algorithm for the *cumulative average*, but that is the average for *all time*, not *for the last 1000 seconds*.  The average for the last 1000 seconds is the *simple moving average*, and you are required to have the historical data to compute it.

Comment: Though, depending on the amount of work required to compute the average of the window, one can optimize it by not having to iterate over the entire window every time one needs the average, but instead keep track of what enters the window and what leaves it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That's correct, but I understood the question to be about the memory burden rather than the computational burden.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the approaches of the simple moving average and the cumulative moving average. Say you cumulate all scores of one second. Then you have a constant memory usage of 1000 items + a few of the current second which you'll cumulate next second.

Depending on the required precision of the application, this may suffice.

Comment: You can hide the granularity of this approach by, in any displays, taking into account 1001 data points, with the last and current datapoint being treated as a single average between the first and last datapoint, weighted based on time.  The currently running second *can* use a cumulative average, so 999.5 of the 1000 data points you're using to calculate your average will be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric wrote no but you can approximate what value you need to subtract from your sum. It is not 100% correct but it could be handy if you don't need exact result.

For ex.

```
lastAveragePerSec = sum / 1000;
sum = sum + (sample / deltaTime) - (lastAveragePerSec / deltaTime);
averagePerSec  = sum / 1000;
```